# Crontab and NMCLI

Tags: cron, nmcli

I have created a script called `connection.sh`, it is used to automatically connect to my vpn :

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli connection up MyVPN
```

I have already tested it, and it works if I launch it manually, but if I use `crontab` to launch it to a specific time it seems it doesn't work.
I stored the script in `/home/MyUser/Scripts`.
So if I type `crontab -l` I get :

```
@reboot /home/MyUser/Scripts/connection.sh
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: did you tried putting `@reboot sh /home/MyUser/Scripts/connection.sh
` in cron ?

Comment: cron launched scripts have reduced environments, and specifically, different paths, always use the full path on executables, or set your own PATH in the script.  Try `/full/path/to/nmcli`

Comment: Ok i did as you tolde me, I did a **whereis nmcli**, I found out it is located in  **/usr/bin/nmcli**, hence my new script is: /usr/bin/nmcli connection up MyVPN.

Again it works when it is manually launched, but it doesn't when I put in crontab

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your shell uses environment variables that have different values then the environment variables that cron job have. Not all of the environment variables have different values but some of them. In not familiar enough with `nmcli` but you have to find out what environment variables it uses and then set them on your script before you call `nmcli`. That should solve your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

`sudo su` before `crontab -e` worked for me.

Comment: Could you add anything to your answer explaining the consequence of doing so and _why_ this solves the issue that the user has?